# Custom name on root and entity XML-elements with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm utilizing the Web API in MVC4 to provide a simple API for my web service. I have read the various posts on SO about using `[XmlType]`, `[XmlRoot]`, `[XmlElement]` etc. on the model to set custom names on the root-element and on the element wrapping each entity, but none of them seem to have an effect at all. The API works fine overall, but the XML-attributes seem to have no effect, leaving me with irrelevant element names.

I've simplified my code somewhat, to make the example more clear, but this is basically what it looks like:

**API controller:**

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<MyViewModel> All()
    {
        return ApiProvider.All()
                        .Select(v => new MyViewModel
                        {
                            SomeId = v.SomeId
                            SomeValue = v.SomeValue
                        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Current XML-response:**

```
<ArrayOfMyViewModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...">
    <MyViewModel>
        <SomeId>3</SomeId>
        <SomeValue>My value</SomeValue>
    </MyViewModel>
</ArrayOfMyViewModel>
```

**Desired XML-response:**

```
<CustomRootName xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...">
    <CustomEntityName>
        <SomeId>3</SomeId>
        <SomeValue>My value</SomeValue>
    </CustomEntityName>
</CustomRootName>
```

I have made no configuration changes to what serializer I'd like to use, or anything like that.

Am I missing something here, or why can I not change the name of the elements? Is there some other approach to take, or some necessary setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just have a class

```
CustomRootName : List<MyViewModel>
```

and return an instance of CustomRootName?

---

[my reply to your comment follows below]

Yes, that was my view when we started our api but ArrayOfMyViewModel is essentially a pseudo wrapper created by the serialiser and creating a one line wrapper per resource list was that much of a bind. Consider when your api gets more complex and you need to support more complex list types, ie:

```
<CustomRootName >
    <RootType>typeB</RootType>
    <CustomEntityName>
        <SomeId>3</SomeId>
        <SomeValue>My value</SomeValue>
    </CustomEntityName>
    <CustomEntityName>
...etc
    </CustomEntityName>
</CustomRootName>
```

You would benefit from a consistent interface. Another benefit we found was with documentation. We document our code using xml-doc tags and then auto-generate the api user guide using xslt and a bit of reflection. If you don’t have a wrapper class then there is knowhere to hang the xml-doc tag. So initially it looks like a pain but I was soon convinced.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sure, that would probably work, at least for the root element. However, it seem to cure the symptom rather than the actual problem. Also, when my API grows, it will be a bit ugly to create new wrapper-classes all the time, just to get the names right.

Comment: Well, put like that, it makes more sense, thanks! I'll give that a try.